# Oracle SQL query count distinct branches

Tags: sql, oracle11g

What I wanted to do is to know the number of employees that have their mgr and have no mgr. The table is like this:

```
Emp     Branch   Mgr   
EmpA    Branch1  Mgr1  
EmpB    Branch2  Mgr2
EmpC    Branch1  Mgr2
EmpD    Branch1  
EmpE    Branch2  Mgr2
EmpF    Branch1  Mgr2
```

And the output that I wanted to get is like this:

```
Branch     HasMgr HasNoMgr
Branch1    3      1
Branch2    2      0
```

already tried this code but the result is wrong

```
SELECT branches,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE mgr IS NULL),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE mgr IS NOT NULL )
FROM tbl GROUP BY branches
```

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  Hint: `GROUP BY` with `COUNT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sub-query to sum up all managers with/without a value. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
SELECT branch,
SUM(case when Mgr is not null then 1 else 0 end) hasmgr,
SUM(case when Mgr is not null then 0 else 1 end) hasnomgr
FROM tbl
GROUP by branch;
```

Comment: Will fix the answer and formatting once i logged into a laptop. Im using my mobile phone right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
With dat as(
Select 'Emp' emp   ,  'Branch' Branch, 'Mgr' as manager  UNION ALL
Select 'EmpA' ,   'Branch1',  'Mgr1'  union all
Select 'EmpB' ,   'Branch2',  'Mgr2' union all
Select 'EmpC' ,  'Branch1' , 'Mgr2' union all
Select 'EmpD' ,   'Branch1'  , null union all
Select 'EmpE'  ,  'Branch2' ,'Mgr2' union all
Select 'EmpF' ,   'Branch1' , 'Mgr2'
)
SELECT Branch,count(manager) hasMgr,sum(case when manager is null then 1 
else 0 end) hasNoMgr FROM dat
group by branch
```

Answer (score 0):

select branch,
    sum(decode(mgr,null,0,1)) as "hasmgr",
    sum(decode(mgr,null,1,0)) as "hasnomgr"
  FROM TAB1
  GROUP BY BRANCH